# MySQL Rank with ties

Tags: mysql, database, ranking

I am new to sql and I have never used variables or conditions in mysql, but know that from other programming languages. Since a few days I try to find a way to rank a user score. I read a lot of articles, and also questions that asked on stackoverflow and finally I found a solution that nearly does it like I want it.

```
SELECT
  score_users.uid,
  score_users.score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := score,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank +1) AS rank
FROM
  score_users,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0) tmp_tbl
WHERE
  score_users.matchday = 1
ORDER BY
  score_users.score DESC
```

But my Problems are tie scores. I don't want to get consecutive ranks, like this:

```
+------------+------+--------+
| uid | name  | rank | score |
+------------+------+--------+
| 4   | Jon   |   1  |  20   |
| 1   | Jane  |   2  |  19   |
| 2   | Fred  |   2  |  19   |
| 9   | July  |   3  |  18   |
| 7   | Mary  |   4  |  17   |
| 3   | Toni  |   5  |  12   |
| 5   | Steve |   5  |  12   |
| 6   | Peter |   6  |  11   |
| 8   | Nina  |   7  |  10   |
+------------+------+--------+
```

I would like to get a result like this:

```
+------------+------+--------+
| uid | name  | rank | score |
+------------+------+--------+
| 4   | Jon   |   1  |  20   |
| 1   | Jane  |   2  |  19   |
| 2   | Fred  |   2  |  19   |
| 9   | July  |   4  |  18   |
| 7   | Mary  |   5  |  17   |
| 3   | Toni  |   6  |  12   |
| 5   | Steve |   6  |  12   |
| 6   | Peter |   8  |  11   |
| 8   | Nina  |   9  |  10   |
+------------+------+--------+
```

I guess I have to create a new temporary table, and some if conditions, but I couldn't find a solution and become desperate!
Also, I have to keep an eye on performance, maybe there are better ways to get the rank on score as I did it? I would be very grateful for hints or some code snippet.

Comment: I'd generate the rank outside of the SQL, as it's easier to do with whatever program you're using (ranking by score is enough). Doing what you're doing is complicated in MySQL!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use another variable to count the same ranks so instead of incrementing `@rank` by 1, you increment `@rank` by the counter value, like this:

```
SELECT
  score_users.uid,
  score_users.score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := score,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank + @i) AS rank,
  IF(@prev <> score, @i:=1, @i:=@i+1) AS counter
FROM
  score_users,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0, @i := 0) tmp_tbl
WHERE
  score_users.matchday = 1
ORDER BY
  score_users.score DESC
```

Comment: Thanks Aziz, this one works very well. I just set @rank to 1 in the sub select, otherwise the ranking started with an 0! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Add another rank field which is always incremented. If the value matches you use your existing rank (not incremented), if not you use your always incremented rank.

```
SELECT
  score_users.uid,
  score_users.score,
  @prev := @curr,
  @curr := score,
  @rank1 := @rank1 + 1,
  @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank, @rank1) AS rank 
FROM
  score_users,
  (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 0, @rank1 := 0) tmp_tbl
WHERE
  score_users.matchday = 1
ORDER BY
  score_users.score DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

On ties, you may want to skip and use current row num to next unmatched score value row as next rank.
Following should help you

```
SELECT
    score_users.uid
  , @curr_score := score_users.score as score,
  , case when @prev_score = @curr_score then @rank := @rank 
         else @rank := ( @curr_row + 1 ) -- <- this is what you require
     end as rank
  , @curr_row := ( @curr_row + 1 ) as curr_row
  , @prev_score := @curr_score
FROM
  score_users,
  ( SELECT @curr_score := 0, @prev_score := 0
         , @curr_row := 0,   @rank := 0 ) initializer
WHERE
  score_users.matchday = 1
ORDER BY
  score_users.score DESC
```

Comment: I'm doing something similar but am putting a 'T' in front of the 2nd tie values - 2, T2. Works with WHEN @prev_val := score then concat('T',@count-1) - but if there are 3 tie values it doesn't do 2, T2, T2 - get 2, T2, T3. Any ideas how to achieve this?