# Rank results by group and allow ties using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following data:

```
enrtryid    categoryid     score
   1             1         90.5
   2             1         90.5
   3             1         89
   4             2         70
   5             2         69
   6             3         78
```

I desire following result:

```
enrtryid    categoryid     score    rank
   1             1         90.5      1
   2             1         90.5      1
   3             1         89        2
   4             2         70        1
   5             2         69        2
   6             3         78        1
```

I have tried using the query

```
SELECT t1.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM overalltally t2 WHERE t2.score> t1.score) +1
AS rank
FROM overalltally t1
ORDER BY `rank` ASC
```

though it ranks all the results sequentially as I don't know where I should place the GROUP BY statement

Comment: Check your spelling :`as rnk ... ORDER BY rank`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118393/mysql-rank-with-ties

Comment: I am voting to reopen since this question is *not exactly the same* as the one cited. The OP here wants to rank results *grouped by category*.

Comment: @NevilleK This question is different since I want to rank per category

Comment: I have voted to reopen this. Based on your current query change the sub query to _(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM overalltally t2 WHERE t2.score> t1.score AND t2.categoryid = t1.categoryid)_ . But it can also be done with a variation on the suggestion by @StefanGehrig below

Comment: @Kickstart: That sub query is grande!! Does the work!! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: The down side of the sub query like that is it needs to be performed on every returned row, hence can be quite slow as the number of rows increases.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
SELECT t1.*, @rank := IF(@previous = t1.score, @rank, @rank + 1) AS rank,
  @previous := t1.score
FROM overalltally t1, (SELECT @previous := null, @rank := 0) tmp_tbl
ORDER BY rank ASC
```

It looks a bit tricky but actually it's a rather standard approach to work around missing ranking functionality in MySQL.

Comment: This ranks all the rows sequentially. How would it rank per group?

Comment: You can add a variable to store and check the category id as well `SELECT t1.*, @rank := IF(@previous_cat = t1.categoryid, IF(@previous = t1.score, @rank, @rank + 1), 1) AS rank,
  @previous := t1.score, @previous_cat = t1.categoryid
FROM 
(
 SELECT enrtryid, categoryid, score
 FROM overalltally
 ORDER BY categoryid, score DESC
) t1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @previous := null, @rank := 0, @previous_cat := 0) tmp_tbl
ORDER BY categoryid, rank ASC`